# Fazendo um select em todas as tabelas de um schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

É possível procurar determinado valor em colunas de outras tabelas?

Exemplo:

Tenho um número: 23028908

Quero procurar em meu banco, todas as colunas que tenha esse valor.

Isso é possível? Como pode ser feito?

Comment: dê uma olhada neste post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2296221/2588695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A seguinte função implementa o que você precisa:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns(
    needle text,
    haystack_tables name[] default '{}',
    haystack_schema name[] default '{public}'
)
RETURNS table(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text)
AS $$
begin
  FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
      SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
      FROM information_schema.columns c
      JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
        (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
      WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
        AND c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema)
        AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text)=%L',
       schemaname,
       tablename,
       columnname,
       needle
    ) INTO rowctid;
    IF rowctid is not null THEN
      RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Para procurar em todas as tabelas de um *schema* por um determinado valor:

```
select * from search_columns('23028908');
```

Para procurar por um valor em uma tabela específica, por nome dinâmico:

```
select * from search_columns('23028908', {tabela});
```

Para procurar por um valor em tabelas cujos nomes vêm de um `select`:

```
select * from grep_columns('23028908', array(select table_name::name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'pessoa%'), array['public']);
```

Mais detalhes [na resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036421/1314276), a qual traduzo aqui.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu tudo certo aqui :)